# How can I stop Xcode from ignoring CoreLocation.framework for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

I'm currently building an iOS app via Xcode that utilises the corelocation.framework, but unfortunately I'm having some trouble.  I downloaded Apple's LocateMe example app, and it worked fine (no errors or warnings) when I ran it via the simulator.

I then built an empty, single-page app and added the corelocation.framework files to it.  When I compile and run it, I get a warning:

```
 (null): Ignoring file/Users/Andrew/Documents/GoogleDrive/Developer/
 Xcode/Apps/GetLocation/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation, file
 was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x c 0x
 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 9 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not
 the architecture being linked (i386):/Users/Andrew/Documents/
 GoogleDrive/Developer/Xcode/Apps/GetLocation/CoreLocation.framework
 /CoreLocation
```

I've tried finding the framework with Finder and adding it, and also dragging the framework from Apple's app to mine.  Both generate the same warning.

I can't say much about the above error other than the file directory seems fine (that's where my app is stored), and i386 I believe represents my MacBook Air's integrated graphics chipset.

I've also tried skimming Apple's app down to a basic level, but it's tough - they decided to make a fairly complicated app to represent the technology.

Unfortunately my knowledge of all this needs improvement and I do feel like I'm jumping the gun with this task, but I have a bet riding on this - need to get this working by the 15th!

So if anyone could provide some guidance about why this warning is being generated, and how I can resolve it, it would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I had a closer look at Apple's LocateMe app, and I noticed that the build is for iOS 3.2.  When I change it to iOS 5.1, it's all fine except for a single error - locationServicesEnabled is deprecated.

Comment: You say you added the corelocation.framework files to it. How did you do this exactly? Are you sure you added the right one? You should be doing that in XCode and not with the finder.

Comment: Have a look at Jessedc's answer and the dialogue we've been having.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your error report, it looks like you've managed to copy the `CoreLocation.framework` into your project directory.

```
file/Users/Andrew/Documents/GoogleDrive/Developer/Xcode/Apps/GetLocation/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
```

I don't know how you've managed to get it here, but the first thing you need to do is **delete the .framework file** from that location, then remove the now *red* reference to CoreLocation.framework in your Xcode project.

Then do the following:

- click on your xcode project in the navigator to bring up the project settings.
- click on your target
- click on 'Build Phases'
- expand the  'Link Binary with Libraries' section
- click the '+' and start typing 'CoreLocation'
- select the one that appears

**A side note:**

When you select the CoreLocation.framework in the 5th bullet point above, make sure you're selecting the CoreLocation.framework that's underneath the iOS 5.1 folder reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it works and hasn't generated an error.  Though one comment, when I only removed references then added the framework in the manner you described, it generated the same error.  When I deleted the framework and sent the files to the trash, it didn't generate an error.  Though I verified that manually adding the file generates the error I found, while linking the framework as you have described imports it correctly.  So thanks!

Comment: Okay but my recommendation isn't to send the framework to the trash so I'm going to revert my answer to what I said originally. If you had to do that then your comment shows that my answer was nearly right in your case.

Comment: I just tried again.  When I only remove references and re-add it properly, the warning remains.  Before the framework was saved as a copy in the app's folder, when I moved it to trash that solved the error.  Now, when I link the binary, it still has the error and I can't move the framework to the trash.  So why is it that when I remove the references, there's clearly still some references remaining?

Comment: I've slightly updated my response in order to gain the correct answer ;)

Comment: Ah still not working.  I know you want the correct answer mark, and I want to give it to you as well as you've contributed a lot, but unfortunately it still isn't resolving the problem... it seems like my file has been permanently tainted.  I'll see if I can find some remaining traces somewhere.

Comment: I've found that the error only appears when I run on the simulator - when I compile for running on my phone, there's no warnings.  My guess is that the issue lies with the build settings.  I'm assuming that the issue doesn't lie with the actual framework.. that would be annoying to check.

Comment: Alright, figured it out - even though CoreLocation.framework didn't appear in the sidebar, it was in the app's folder when I looked with Finder.  I deleted the framework there, and added it, and it worked fine.  Perhaps put some emphasis on the need to delete the framework if it's stored in the app's folder as that was half the issue, then I'll give you the mark ;) Thanks for your patience!  Just want to make sure we've got a clear Q&A so that others don't have to go through this.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've never worked so hard for 15 points ;)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!  You have well and truly deserved the tick! :)